# Domain Driven Design in Node.js Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, domain-driven-design

*TL; DR;
I'm looking for trite example of DDD node.js application.*

---

Hi,

I'm going to create node application. I wonder that I can not find any example of application with business logic separated in domain.

OK, there are some examples like:
https://github.com/adrai/node-cqrs-domain - but this is whole CQRS with event sourcing implementation.

My idea is to do that like that:

```
//domain/book.js
function Book(title, author)
{
  this._title = title;
  this._author = author;
}

// domain methods ...

//infrastructure/persistance/repository/book-repository.js
function BookRepository()
{}

BookRepository.prototype.save(book)
{
  var bookModel = mappers.mapToOrm(book);
  return bookModel.save();
}

// [...] get, getAll, getNextId

//infrastructure/persistance/orm/book.js
//using http://bookshelfjs.org/
var Book = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'books'
});

//infrastructure/mappers/book-mapper.js
function mapToOrm(book) {
  //mapping [...]
  return new persistance.Book();
}

function mapToDomain(domain) {
  //mapping [...]
  return new domain.Book();
}
```

but on the other hand I've never seen any similar solution (with domain model, orm model, repository and mappers). Am I thinking in the right way? Maybe there is no reason to separate business logic in domain in node.js applications. If so, why? If not, can you send me an example of DDD implementation or improve my code?

**[2017/01/13]**

I've created sample application in TypeScript. For now without repositories and not much services. Issues and pull requests are welcome.
https://github.com/dawiddominiak/ddd-typescript-bin-packing-problem-solution

Comment: There's no reason why you couldn't apply DDD tactical patterns in JS. The principal reason you haven't seen this yet is the same reason you haven't seen design patterns and elegant application architectures for a long time in JS: it used to be a hacking language which no one was taking seriously. DDD haven't really made it's way to the JS world yet when you compare to the hype it has in .NET, Java, Scala etc.

Comment: Do not forget that at it's core, DDD is not defined by it's tactical patterns but it's strategic patterns: Bounded Contexts, Ubiquitous Language, etc.

Comment: ""the hype it has in .NET, Java, Scala etc." hmm or maybe those communities are more susceptible to hype :) you also don't see many of the non sense OOP patterns in non enterprisy languages because they are simply not needed

Comment: Your response is Mongoose instance and static methods

Comment: GitHub search yields some interesting results, although not all are node: https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=domain+language%3AJavaScript&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=JavaScript&l=

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZVdjRNArnw&ab_channel=MichaelGuay

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm very new to Node.js world.

But I believe if you do your work using **TypeScript with Node** you can force most of DDD principles to be used.

The problem "and advantage in the same time" in node.js that there aren't so restrictions like we have in OOP languages like C# or Java. and this freedom "and messy" of JavaScript **making create robust complex DomainModel and Business logic very hard**

Comment: This is what unit testing is for, and you can still create models they just aren't as verbose.

Comment: DDD can be built very nicely without TypeScript. Saying that one language is 'messy' and DDD is hard to make with it, stems from lack of knowledge of that language.

Comment: @Exitos I'm not talking about testing the logic of your app. I'm talking about the rules of DDD that depends on some restrictions that we already have in the OOP. Like private setters, value objects, abstraction, and inheritance...

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. DDD is more suitable with OOP languages and the most powerful proof to this is this question. cheers ;)

Answer (score 5):

I'm looking to do the same thing at the moment, and I'm coming from the Ruby world.  So, let me do 2 things:

1. Point you to the best Ruby implementation I've seen of Domain-Driven Design I have found, Hanami: http://hanamirb.org/guides/models/overview/ which you could use as a reference.
2. Discuss what I'm finding (literally right now, as I type) to attempt to find the analogs in Node.

I've found this page: https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-nodejs

which catalogs a ton of high-quality / high-popularity Node packages.

The first thing is, we need something that is going to do validation and schema construction for our Domain Models.  Just looking at the first entry in the data validation section, Joi seems to be a decent choice for that:

https://github.com/hapijs/joi

For Persistence of the domain objects, I'm just setting up a stub object, borrowing from Hanami's interface:

```
var repo = {
  find: function(entity_name, id) {
    //  - Fetch an entity from the collection by its ID
  },
  create: function(entity_name, data) {
    //  – Create a record for the given data and return an entity
  },
  update: function(entity_name, id, data) {
    //  – Update the record corresponding to the id and return the updated entity
  },
  delete: function(entity_name, id) {
    //  – Delete the record corresponding to the given entity
  },
  all: function(entity_name) {
    //  - Fetch all the entities from the collection
  },
  query: function(entity_name, query_object) {

  },
  first: function(entity_name) {
    //  - Fetch the first entity from the collection
  },
  last: function(entity_name) {
    //  - Fetch the last entity from the collection
  },
  clear: function(entity_name) {
    //  - Delete all the records from the collection
  }
}

module.exports = repo
```

whether you choose to use `Bookshelf`, `Sequelize`, or even the `LoopBack` framework, you can code an object that is going to fit the above interface that then does the dirty work of integrating with those frameworks.

If I were to try different ORM's, I would create a different repo object for each of the above.  Notice that as I've written it, the repo is a singleton that is aware of different entities and how to persist them.  In many cases, this will no doubt delegate to different repository objects on a per-entity basis.  However, that might not always be true. a simple in-memory repo, could just have an array of objects for each entity.

That leaves Services/Interactors - The functions/classes that actually do work.  These are easy - they are the ones that take a domain object, perform some business logic, and in the CRUD cases, make a call out to the Repository. A probably-syntactically-wrong example:

```
const repository = require('./myFileRepository')

function createBook(bookEntity) { 

  if(bookEntity.valid?) { 
    repository.create('book', bookEntity)
    return true
  }
  else {
    return { error: 'book not valid' }
  }
}

module.exports = createBook
```

for the Service functions, I just today learned about Node Machines, and they seem like a really smart idea:  http://node-machine.org

they seem to be a JS-attempt at monads + documentation. so I'm considering writing them up like that.

anyway, given it's been a year since your post, you've probably moved on.  hope this helps you / the community!

Comment: It would be even better if  the repository was passed in to the function instead of imported directly!

Comment: 2 years on, and I now know that the _correct_ answer to how to design an app is to do away with OOP and instead use a strictly typed language and Functional Programming :).

I learned FP on the job over the last 6 months, but for posterity, I hear a good guide is "Professor Frisbee's Mostly Adequate Guide to FP"; meaning to get around to actually reading it myself soon to see what I still may not know.

Answer (score 0):

Many would argue that JavaScript is NOT well suited to modeling a complex problem into a domain model and then into code.  That's especially the case if the domain is in business, industry and commerce, rather than in computer or data science.

I'm not saying one can't create a domain model in JavaScript.  Just like one could create one in C.  But does that mean one should?

The example you give uses some terminology in domain-driven design, but misses the whole purpose and ethos of applying it.

Comment: What language features are missing exactly so that you can't build a system based on metaphors in javascript?

Comment: js has no threads, so it's not possible to pretend you're operating on array but actually do database queries (these would have to be async)