# Domain Driven Design for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, domain-driven-design

I'm currently in the process of architecting a Node.js microservice-based application, and I'd like to make use of Domain Driven Design as a *guideline* for structuring the individual services. I have a few questions on this as follows:

1. As far as I understand, the domain layer should typically contain repository interfaces, and specific implementations of these interfaces should then be created in your infrastructure layer. This abstracts the underlying storage/technical concerns out of your domain layer. In the context of my project, seeing as JavaScript does not **natively** support things like interfaces, how would one go about achieving a similar effect?
2. One service in particular will be handling authentication by means of OAuth. Would one typically classify OAuth-related logic as an application service? Or would it fall under the infrastructure layer? My understanding is that it's not infrastructure-related, nor is it related to the core domain, but is still required as part of serving the application to clients. Hence, I've placed it within the application layer for now.
3. Following on from point 2, where would OAuth-related entities/repositories (i.e. tokens/clients) best be placed? I'm tempted to keep them in the domain layer along with my other entities/repositories, even though they aren't technically a business concern.

Some notes to add to the above:

1. I'm **not** keen on using TypeScript (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027990/domain-driven-design-in-node-js-application)).
2. I am fully aware that some may consider JavaScript as being non-suitable for DDD-type approaches. I'm familiar with some of the pitfalls, and once again, I'm using DDD as a guideline.

On a side note, I have come up with the following project structure, which was heavily inspired by [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/folder-and-namespace-structure-with-ddd) great example of a DDD-based project in Laravel:

```
app/
----app.js
----package.json
----lib/
--------app/
------------service/
----------------oauth.js
----------------todo.js
--------domain/
------------list/
----------------model.js
----------------repository.js
----------------service.js
------------task/
----------------model.js
----------------repository.js
----------------service.php
--------http/
------------controller/
----------------list.js
----------------task.js
------------middleware/
----------------auth.js
----------------error.js
--------infrastructure/
------------db.js
------------logger.js
------------email.js
```

I would love to hear any thoughts you may have on this layout. I'm fully aware that the topic of project structure is somewhat opinion-based, but I'm always keen to hear what others have to say.

Comment: Do you think that a DDD design tells you what names you need to pick for sub-directories to use in your project?  The little I know about it sounds like it's not at that level of detail.  It seems like it's more about making sure you architect the business model logic in one place and keep all the other supporting stuff (like user auth and other plain infrastructure stuff, for example) that is required but has nothing to do with the actual business logic in a nice convenient separate place.

Comment: @jfriend00 completely agree. That is, in my mind, the main driver of DDD - build around a "core business domain". Perhaps for clarification, I'll edit my post to highlight the fact that I'm not too focused on the structure/naming, more on ensuring correct classification/separation.

Comment: But your entire question sounds like it's about what directories to put things in rather than defining what in your application is the core business logic and how can it be structured separately from everything else.  Frankly, where the everything else goes is not all that important (e.g what's a service and what's infrastructure).  Those are just labels that should be chosen to make the layout of your project clear to others and convenient to use.

Comment: As I understand it, the main DDD goal is to make sure you know what the core business logic is and how that is structured and how it's written to be independent of all the supporting code that really has nothing to do with core business logic.  In many ways, it's no different than a very good object oriented design with an extra emphasis on making sure business logic code is not mixed in with non-business logic code.

Comment: @jfriend00 - thanks for all the input. Having re-read my question, I fully understand where you're coming from. I've had a go at making the question a bit more conceptual, with less focus on my project structure. I have still kept in the proposed structure as a sideline question, as although there is no "right" way to structure projects, there are certainly many wrong ways. I'm aware this is very opinionated, but I'm keen to see what suggestions (if any) the community has.

Comment: Tbh, I don't think there are "wrong" way to structure your project. From time to time when starting a new project or a new component, I set up everything single file in the same folder / namespace. And then I start to refactor, and move together. It avoids focusing on infrastructural or design related name and more on business, which is what ddd is all about.

Answer (score 9):

Have you considered [wolkenkit](https://www.wolkenkit.io/)?

It's a CQRS and event-sourcing framework for Node.js and JavaScript, that works pretty well with domain-driven design (DDD). It might give you a good idea of how to structure your code, and also a runtime to execute things without having to re-invent the wheel.

I know the guys behind it and they invested 3-4 years of thoughts, blood and sweat into this.

Comment: Adding to this, great talk about Node.js DDD with an example by one of wolkenkit's creators at the International Javascript Conference 2018: https://youtu.be/rolfJR9ERxo

Answer (score 1):

Domain-Driven Design guides decomposition of a system into a set of bounded contexts/services/microservices. However, the way you design each service is individual and depends on the service's business domain. For example, your business's core domain services and supporting domain services should be architected in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this question is quite old, I think it will be useful to add a precision on your first interrogation :

> As far as I understand, the domain layer should typically contain repository interfaces, and specific implementations of these interfaces should then be created in your infrastructure layer. This abstracts the underlying storage/technical concerns out of your domain layer. In the context of my project, seeing as JavaScript does not natively support things like interfaces, how would one go about achieving a similar effect?

JavaScript does not provide interface. Instead of mimicking OOP concepts, why not have a look to more functional ones? Higher-order functions are very well suited for javascript, you can use them to "declare" dependencies and inject them at runtime :

```
const { FooData } = require('./data');

const getFooOfId = (getFooOfIdImpl = async (fooId) => { throw new Error(`Can't retrieved foo of id ${fooId} : missing implementation`) }) => async fooId => {
  try {
    const fooData = await getFooOfIdImpl(fooId);
    return FooData(fooData);
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(`Unable to retrieve Foo with id ${fooId}`);
  }
}

/*
This function is used to build a concrete implementation, for example with an in-memory database :
const inMemoryFooDatabase = {
  foo17: {
    id: 'foo17',
    foo: 'a foo value',
    bar: 'a bar value',
    foobaz: 1234,
  },
};
const getFooOfIdFromInMemoryDatabase = getFooOfId(fooId => inMemoryFooDatabase[fooId])
*/

module.exports = {
  getFooOdId,
}
```

Nothing prevents you to bypass totally this function because there is no strong type-checking in javascript, but it acts as a declaration of your domain "interfaces" needs.

If you want to learn more about this, you can read my post on this subject : [Domain-Driven Design for JavaScript developers](https://medium.com/spotlight-on-javascript/domain-driven-design-for-javascript-developers-9fc3f681931a)